# Import html table into html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have a fully functional html file right now that has a lot of content, and I'd like to increase readability by storing the table in a separate file. The table data is about 3,000 lines of html. The current structure is:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- Lots of content -->

    <table>
        <!-- Lots of data -->
    </table>

    <!-- Other content -->

    <script>
        <!-- Set up as table as datatable (jQuery plug-in) -->
        <!-- Add dynamic formatting to table -->
    </script>
</body>
```

How can I replace the `<table>`...`</table>` with just a call to another html file that contains all of the data, so that I can still do all of the javascript stuff to the table?

Comment: Why a different html file and not just a json file with the data?

Comment: I've never used json - I'm not opposed to it, I just didn't realize that was an option.

Comment: Ok, cool no problem. The cool thing with JSON is you can do async calls with jquery's AJAX api. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: So to use JSON, would I do something like `jQuery.ajax( "tableData.html [, settings ] )` ? Where would this go? Inside the table container div in my main page?

Comment: No, you would have to make a `json` file. Forget the html :). If I were you I would leave json out of it for now and learn it another day

Comment: I suppose you could use the `<iframe>` tag as a simple solution to your problem.

Comment: @Mikey Thanks for the json idea - that's what I ended up going with, using AngularJS. It's taking a while to learn, but it will definitely be worth it in the future.

Comment: @lg22woo No problem. Good to hear you are using AngularJS. It is an awesome framework.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do this with a GET command and then appending it do a div in your body where you want the table to end up.

The code for importing data would look like this:

```
    $.ajax(
    {url:"tabledata.html",
     dataType:"text"}).done(
     function(data){
        $('#id_of_div_to_append_to').html(data);
     });
```

Also, you'd need to add a div to append the data in your HTML:

```
<body>
    <!-- Lots of content -->

    <div id = "id_of_div_to_append_to"></div>

    <!-- Other content -->

    <script>
        <!-- Set up as table as datatable (jQuery plug-in) -->
        <!-- Add dynamic formatting to table -->
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: My main page is index.html, which contains a table container div, and the page with the data is tableData.html. So would I put your code in index.html? And would it be `$.get("tableData.html", function(data) {   $('#tableContainer').append(data); })`  ?

Comment: @lg22woo Where is your tableData.html located? In the same folders as index.html?

Comment: @lg22woo Yes. the code should go in index.html. The code assumes your data file is in the same folder as index.html. Try it out, let me know what happens.

Comment: @Mikey Yes, they're in the same folder.

Comment: @userbd Nothing shows up. I have this: `<div id="tableContainer">
   <script>
   $.get("tableData.html", function(data) {
    $('#tableContainer').append(data);
   })
   </script>
 
  </div>`

Comment: @lg22woo Try this code -- this worked for me self-contained locally. I will update my answer to reflect the changes `<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $( document ).ready(function()
 {
  $.get("tabledata.html", function(data) { $('#tableContainer').html(data.documentElement.outerHTML); });
 });
</script> 
</head>
<body>
 A<div id="tableContainer"> loading </div>
</body>`

Comment: Nothing came up, and the console logged: _The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol._

Comment: How much structure does my tableData.html need? Should it be `<!doctype html> <html> <body> <table> ... </table> </body> </html>` ?

Comment: Shouldn't need any of that, just the html to insert. The code worked for me. One alternative is to treat the file as text instead of html. To do that, replace  the get statement with `$.ajax(
   {url:"tabledata.html",
    dataType:"text"}).done(
    function(data){
     $('#tableContainer').html(data);
    });`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very complex solution to my question, but if you have the time to learn Angular, I'd recommend it:

https://www.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js

Angular allowed me to make my html much more readable and dynamic.